# Hosting Web application - best practices

Tags: reactjs, database, deployment, devops, nestjs

So I have a web application where the Frontend is written in React and the backend is written in NodeJs/NestJs, and are in the stages of deploying the application. I have a Linode server running Ubuntu, and my initial thoughts was to install Docker & Kubernetes (I will need a couple more servers) and then spin up containers for the front and backend, and  a separate server hosting the database. Since the requirements are high uptime, scaleability and modularity.

So is this a good way to go about setting up the application? Are there any pros and cons with this setup except pricing because of the amount of servers needed? Or are there any other options available that could be more benefitial?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It depends if you want to make DevOps job or not, and also about the budget you have.

If you really want to stay in control of your clusters, scalability of them and money is not a worry, then kubernetes is a good alternative.

Disclaimer: I don't know Linode and have no idea if there is some GCP compatible services.

For front-end, you said it was react: The hosting service of firebase, here's [a tutorial](https://medium.com/cwi-software/publishing-your-front-end-to-firebase-hosting-afc054f4ef26).
And the good news is that you can alternatively use any cloud platform with a storage service like Google Storage, AWS S3 or Azure.

For back-end, I would suggest [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine) or functions, I'm having a great experience using App Engine and is a lot easier to configure than any pods, deployments, ingress and all steps to deploy a kubernetes cluster. I'm not really sure if you can use NestJs with Cloud Functions and all FaaS options.

Also, this suggestion will make you spend a lot less than a whole k8s infrastructure.

But, of course, it depends on your case.